# Seeing “runtime error: ‘chart’ is null or not an object”

Tags: ole, amibroker

Active window on the application is a chart but when i run the javascript using `cscript Amibroker.js`, i see error:Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'chart' is null or not an object on line `chart.GotoDateTime(dateTime);`

```
// Define the year, month, and date
var year = 2023;
var month = 11;
var date = 11;

// Create a Date object
var dateObj = new Date(year, month - 1, date); // Subtract 1 from month

// Create the main OLE automation object for AmiBroker
var AB = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application");

// Get the active chart
var chart = AB.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Chart;

// Format the date in the required format
var dateTime = dateObj.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2) + " 00:00:00";

// Go to the specific date
chart.GotoDateTime(dateTime);
WScript.Echo(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: `chart` is null or not an object," indicates that the `chart` object is not being retrieved correctly from the `AmiBroker` application. This could be due to a few reasons, such as no active chart being open or the `AmiBroker` application not being properly initialized.

**Try using a delay:** There might be a timing issue where the script is trying to access the `chart` object before it's fully available. You can try adding a delay before attempting to access the `chart` object, using the `WScript.Sleep` method.

**For example:**

```
// Create the main OLE automation object for AmiBroker
var AB = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application");

// Wait for a few seconds to ensure the application is fully loaded
WScript.Sleep(2000);  // Wait for 2 seconds

// Get the active chart
var chart = AB.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Chart;
```

Comment: Seeing the same error, i changed sleep to up to 5 seconds.

Comment: @erukumk it works?

Comment: No it does not work, i am seeing the same error after adding the sleep

Comment: @erukumk provide your code to see the problem properly

Comment: I am unable to add the entire code here, but the change i made is same as your original answer. Rest all is same as in original question

// Create the main OLE automation object for AmiBroker
var AB = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application");

// Wait for a few seconds to ensure the application is fully loaded
WScript.Sleep(2000);  // Wait for 2 seconds

// Get the active chart
var chart = AB.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Chart;